# SQL full join in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, join

I'm trying to join two tables but can't get the SQL right. My SQL statement is far more complex than the below SQL but the below SQL will do to show the principle. I get an invalid identifier exception when trying to refer to t or p. How come I cannot refer to these? I'm using Oracle DB.

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT * FROM transactions t) FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM payments p) ON (t.id = p.trans_id));
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "P"."TRANS_ID": invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not really giving your querys an alias, you should do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM transactions) t 
FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM payments) p 
ON (t.id = p.trans_id);
```

Of course, assuming that you are using real derived tables instead of those simple `SELECT`s, otherwise you should just use the tables directly.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thanks for your fast reply!

Answer (score 2):

The aliases are in the wrong place. The alias for a derived table should be just *after* the closing parenthesis:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT * FROM transactions) t
FULL JOIN
(SELECT * FROM payments) p
ON t.id = p.trans_id
```

Note that it makes no sense to use derived tables with such a simple query. I assume that you do actually need the derived tables and that you just simplified your query for the question.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thanks for your fast reply!